# How to construct or use the sub conditional of the ternary operator

Tags: php, conditional-operator

I current confuse or this would be my problem where I need to produce a sub conditional using the ternary operator of javascript. I will share to you the sample php if condition where this condition is my reference. My Goal is to convert this php conditional to ternary operator.

```
if($first_variable && $second_variable > 0)
{
    if($third_variable > 0)
    {
        echo '<td bg="green">Positive</td>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<td bg="red">Negative</td>';
    }
}
```

Hope someone help me how to convert the php condition to ternary operator. Thank you.

Comment: Why is this tagged Javascript and jQuery when it's about PHP syntax?

Comment: sorry for that i will edit it

Comment: I've already done it for you

Comment: how it works? is there a sample script for my reference, to have a sub conditional using ternary operator?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
echo $first_variable && $second_variable > 0 ? $third_variable > 0
        ? '<td bg="green">Positive</td>' : '<td bg="red">Negative</td>' : '';
```

You may want to revisit  [PHP Ternary Operator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)